# Employer refused to return my Passport

Tags: passports, legal, thailand

"I work in Thailand.What legal action can i take against my employer as he firstly refused to give my passport back after that made excuses that i have it and will give you and now he is saying he doesn't have it."

As far as I know its illegal, can please someone help me and guide me about  to take Legal action in Thailand.

Comment: Have you contacted the police? Or if a foreigner in Thailand, your embassy?

Comment: No, i have never been in such a situation and wanted to know whats  best to do.You think i should call Thai embassy? Yes I am a foreigner here in Thailand.

Comment: not travel. perhaps workplace, but it's legal advice, so not on topic there as written. Maybe legal.se?

Comment: I do not know, but it can be important to those that do know more. You can at least tell your employer that you will need to report that passport missing at the police station and will have to name him as the last one to hold it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for legal advice

Comment: @axe this is very illegal he is keeping you from leaving the country!

Comment: @axe there is no Thai embassy in Thailand.  Go to the embassy or consulate of *your country.*

Comment: @hownowbrowncow how to come out of this situation,I want my passport back?

Comment: @axe you need to contact your own embassy, the one for the country which passport it is.

Comment: Go to the country that issued your passport. Report it as stolen (and it will be cancelled). (Probably) pay to get a new passport (some countries do this for free under certain circumstances). If under any specific visas, apply to Thai Immigration to get the reinstated in your new passport.

Answer (score 3):

Contact your country's embassy or consulate to report the issue, as officially the passport belongs to the country, not to you. Most embassies will not do much directly on your behalf, but most do have lists of suggested lawyers they can give you, through which you can pursue legal action.

You can contact the Royal Thai Police and file a complaint.  But if it is a he said you said issue, they tend to side with the Thai side of the story.

Ultimately it will come down to what agreements were made when you were hired.  And then weighing those agreements against Thai laws.

Comment: I didn't signed a bond with them when i was hired. If it goes in their favor then what should I do?Stay there until I die?:s there must be some solution to it.I want to go to my country.

Comment: Ultimately, your employer can not sieze property of your goverment permanently.  Working through a lawyer and the RTP, you will be able to resolve the issue.  First thing Monday morning contact your embassy and make sure your boss knows you have reported it to the embassy and police.